# How to complete Sprint and move to next Sprint in TFS Online

Tags: tfs

I'm trying out TFS online and using the Scrum template. I have Sprint 1 under `Current` and then I have Sprints 2 - 6 listed under `Future`.

Once I have all tasks moved to the `Done` column, how do I close out Sprint 1 and make Sprint 2 the `Current` Sprint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the iteration dates. Once you've applied dates to the iterations, the Current iteration is based on today's date.

Comment: Ah, gotcha! That worked! Thank you so much!